# Python in Atom: float object not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, atom-editor

Im working with python on atom for the first time and i've been having some trouble while executing part of my code

I´ve defined this class:

```
class Installment(object):

    def __init__(self, pName, pPercentage):

        self.name = pName
        self.percentage = pPercentage
        self.grade = 0.0
        self.contribution = 0.0

    def givePercentage(self):

        return (self.percentage)

    def grade(self, pGrade):

        self.grade = pGrade

        self.contribution = giveContribution() * pGrade

    def giveContribution(self):

        return (self.contribution)
```

But when I try to test the functions ive done:

```
midterm1 = Installment("Parcial 1", 0.25)

print(midterm1.givePercentage())

print(midterm1.giveContribution())

midterm1.grade(3.4)
```

Atom throws the following:

```
0.25

0.0

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Oscar Ramirez\Documents\Python\Tracker\Installment.py", 
line 28, in 

    midterm1.grade(3.4)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

[Finished in 0.609s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an attribute `self.grade` and a function `def grade(self, pGrade):`. When you do `midterm1.grade`, it assumes you mean the first one. You are not able to access the second one.

To avoid name collision issues like this, change the name of either the function or the attribute. Perhaps `def set_grade_and_contribution`?

---

Also, this is unrelated to your problem, but it is typically not idiomatic Python to make "getter" methods that do nothing but return an attribute. There's not much point in doing `print(midterm1.giveContribution())` when `print(midterm1.contribution)` would work just as well and require less code.